# How to add the WYSIWYG editor in customer form in admin area

Tags: magento-1.9, php, wysiwyg, customer-attribute

i create a custom attribute in customer form,that is textarea, in that i need to add the WYSIWYG editor.

[image]

your suggestion and idea will help me more

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me.
First of all, the attribute `education` must have the `frontend_input` set to `editor`. If you already have the attribute change the value of the `frontend_input` column in the `eav_attribute` table to `editor`.
If you are willing to start from scratch here is a full module that worked for me.
Let's call the module `StackExchange_Education`.
You will need the following files.

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_Education.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Education>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Customer/></depends>
        </StackExchange_Education>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Education/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_Education>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </StackExchange_Education>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_edit_tab_account>StackExchange_Education_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account</customer_edit_tab_account><!-- rewrite the account edit block -->
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <stackexchange_education_setup><!-- setup resource for adding the attribute -->
                <setup>
                    <module>StackExchange_Education</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </stackexchange_education_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <stackexchange_education>
                    <file>stackexchange_education.xml</file><!-- layout file for enabling the editor -->
                </stackexchange_education>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Education/sql/stackexchange_education_setup/install-1.0.0.php` - the install script that adds the attribute. If you already have the attribute and you just change the frontend_input to editor you don't need this

```
<?php
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'education', array(
    'type'      => 'text',
    'label'     => 'Education',
    'input'     => 'editor',
    'position'  => 120,
    'required'  => false,//or true
    'is_system' => 0,
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'education');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/Education/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Account.php` - the rewrite of the admin account block

```
<?php
class StackExchange_Education_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account
{
    public function initForm()
    {
        parent::initForm();
        $form = $this->getForm();
        $educationElem = $form->getElement('education');
        $educationElem->setConfig(Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig());
        return $this;
    }
}
```

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/stackexchange_education.xml` - the layout file for enabling the editor

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <update handle="editor" />
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setCanLoadTinyMce"><load>1</load></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

Clear the cache and give it a try.

Comment: i tried with your way, but still no response.

Comment: @senthil. strange. I actually implemented this on my side and it worked nicely

Comment: Thanks Marius this helped me out. adding a Wysiwyg to the customer attributes. @senthil, over 4 years ago but in case anyone else has issues, the key was the `<update handle="editor" />` in the layout XML, needs to be there to make admin recognise the "editor" inputtype. Once I Flushed Caches all is good!

Comment: Turns out on save the admin system freaks out about finding a data model for "editor" (the frontend class), you can force it to save as a textarea by adding `'data' => 'eav/attribute_data_textarea'` to your addAttribute call in the setup file.